# MVC 5 Ajax BeginForm POST 404 Not Found

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with my MVC application.

My controller:

```
 public class CustomerController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customers customers)
    {
        //do something
        return View();
    }
}
```

My view:

```
    @model Insurance_System.Models.Customers
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> 

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Dodawanie nowego klienta</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "CustomerController", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @required = "require", @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Resources.InsuranceCustomer.FirstName })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @required = "require", @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Resources.InsuranceCustomer.LastName })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                  // and other field form
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Common.Save" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                }
                @*<div>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                    </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this form in my other View:

```
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Customer/CreateModal.cshtml")
```

CreateModel (form) render on bootstrap modalpopup. 
When I fill form and submit changes, browser shows an error:

> POST http://localhost:8001/CustomerController/Create 404 (Not Found)
>   - [jquery-3.1.0.js:9392]

I start play with MVC, so far I coped eny problem:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `Controller` suffix when specifying the controller name.

Use `Customer` instead of `CustomerController`.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", null,new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **Ajax.BeginForm**  doesn't work and returns a **404 Error** because the file is to large to upload.

1. Try uploading a smaller file;
2. If the first step works, try changing the web.config upload size;

I found this solution when I had a similar problem